# Does an Array (UUID[ ]) break 1NF?

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql

My question is whether the inclusion of a field that contains an array of UUIDs breaks the [Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization/), in a table that before the inclusion of the array was in NF?

Original table:

```
CREATE TABLE Floor
(
    "Floor-ID" uuid NOT NULL,
    "Floor-Floor" smallint NOT NULL,
    "Floor-Desc" varchar(300),
    CONSTRAINT "Floor-PK" PRIMARY KEY ("Floor-ID")
);
```

New table, including UUID array:

```
CREATE TABLE Floor
(
    "Floor-ID" uuid NOT NULL,
    "Floor-Floor" smallint NOT NULL,
    "Floor-Desc" varchar(300),
    "Floor-Room-IDs" uuid[] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Floor-PK" PRIMARY KEY ("Floor-ID")
);
```

Does the inclusion of uuid[] break Normal Form?
(The same UUID could theoretically exist in multiple UUID arrays on multiple rows.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short - yes.

1NF is defined as:

> relation is in first normal form if the domain of each attribute contains only atomic values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain.

In other words, none of the fields should have elements which are themselves sets (or arrays, for that matter).

Comment: If an array of UUIDs is considered a “single value” in the domain, it’s perfectly fine, though. It depends on the context.

Comment: If you can treat any of its values as a singular value, it breaks 1NF. If you can't, then holding it in a array is indeed inconsequential.