# How to construct a Junction Table for Many-to-Many relationship without breaking Normal Form

Tags: sql, database-normalization, junction-table

I have these two tables, Company and Owner.
Right now they are both in Normal Form, but I need to create a [Many-to-Many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship between them, since **one Company can have many Owners** and **one Owner can have many Companies**.

I have previously gotten an answer to whether adding an array of CompanyOwners (with Owner UUIDs) to Companies would break Normal Form, [It will break Normal Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720523/does-an-array-uuid-break-1nf), and have been able to gather that what could be used is a [Junction Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620645/best-method-for-storing-a-list-of-user-ids).

My question is as following: **will the creation of an additional Junction Table as shown below, break Normal Form?**

```
-- This is the junction table.
CREATE TABLE CompanyOwners(
    Connection-ID UUID NOT NULL, // Just the ID (PK) of the relationship.
    Company-ID UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES Company (Company-ID),
    Owner-ID UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES Owner (Owner-ID),
    CONSTRAINT "CompanyOwners" PRIMARY KEY ("Connection-ID")
)
```

Comment: spot on, no worries, go ahead :)

Comment: There is no specif "normal form."  There are many levels of normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms.   Having too much normalization can be just as bad, if not worse, than having too little.   What you are doing is exactly right, especially including a primary key for the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure allows duplicate data. For example, it allows data like this. (UUIDs abbreviated to prevent horizontal scrolling.)

```
Connection_id            Company_id               Owner_id
--
b56f5dc4...af5762ad2f86  4d34cd58...a4a529eefd65  3737dd70...a359346a13b3
0778038c...ad9525bd6099  4d34cd58...a4a529eefd65  3737dd70...a359346a13b3
8632c51e...1876f6d2ebd7  4d34cd58...a4a529eefd65  3737dd70...a359346a13b3
```

Each row in a relation should have a distinct meaning. This table allows millions of rows that mean the same thing.

Something along these lines is better. It's in 5NF.

```
CREATE TABLE CompanyOwners(
    Company_ID UUID NOT NULL references Company (Company_ID),
    Owner_ID UUID NOT NULL references Owner (Owner_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY (Company_ID, Owner_ID)
);
```

Standard SQL doesn't allow "-" in identifiers.

Comment: I understand that a single Owner cannot own a Single company Two times, which I presume is the duplicate incident you are referring to. But it does not break Normal Form, which is my main concern.

The info about the disallowing of "-" is very useful, thank you very much.
Do you know if newer versions of PostgreSQL 9.x allows more symbols than Standard SQL ?

Comment: Mike, thanks a lot for the clarification with the added duplicate UUIDs example. I now understand what you were talking about and will change the design to incorporate your suggestion. Very much appreciated. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is fine as it is but you could add a couple of more columns like

```
DateOwned Datetime  --<-- when the owner bought the company 
DateSold Datetime  --<-- when a the owner sold the compnay
```

After all you would want to know something like is company is still owned by the same owner, and keep track of the company's ownership history etc.